# Matplotlib: Plotting multiple lines from a 2D list

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble plotting multiple lines from a 2D list. 
I currently have the below dataset.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
y = [[0.32,1.25,2.36,3.36,3.52],[0.32,1.25,2.36,3.36,3.52]]
```

and to plot this I implemented

```
for i in range(len(y)):
    for x in range(len(y[i])):
        plt.plot(x[x], y[I][x])
plt.show()
```

How can I have it so that I have multiple lines in one graph thus plotting it from a 2d array?

Comment: Thank you, but I don't really get your comment. What is T?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid a loop, you can transform `y` into a numpy array, [transpose it with `y.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) so that it is aligned with the `x` array and then simply plot both arrays:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 5)
y = np.asarray([[0.32,1.25,2.36,3.36,3.52],[0.2,1.5,2.6,2.3,1.5]])
print(y)

plt.plot(x, y.T)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the for loop:

```
plt.plot(x,y[0],x,y[1])
plt.show()
```

this should give you the result you were looking for. However, your graphs are identical so it'll always look like one graph. If you get different data it'll work.

[image: graph example with different y data]

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However what happens if I have a lot of data. I don't want to do x,y[200]

Comment: then you could make a for loop that increments through the arrays in y and just say plt.plot(x,y[i])

Comment: This will work in the same way. just plt.show() at the end